# Connect to Visual Studio GIT repository for Deploy HQ

Tags: git, visual-studio, deployment, azure-devops

I am trying to connect to my repository which is held in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) via Deploy HQ.

www.deployhq.com

Has anyone done this before, am I missing something?

I receive the following error from DeployHQ:

```
Oh dear. We couldn't add your repository.
There were problems with the following fields:
URL is an invalid format, should be one of;
ssh://user@server/project.git
git@server:user/project.git
user@server:project.git
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You'll need to generate an SSH key for your account](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate). The Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) documentation is pretty descriptive on the process. This feature is being deployed to all VSTS accounts with the deployment of this week. [If it hasn't been enabled for yours it should in a few days.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2016/05/10/would-you-like-ssh-turned-on-for-your-team-services-account/)

When that is done you can use this syntax `ssh://user@server/project.git` to connect.